# How to handle error : "aws_mobile_analytics_app_id is not defined " while creating ionic3 aws project?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, analytics, ionic3, aws-mobilehub

I am new to ionic 3. I tried to create project in ionic 3 .

and selected project type as :

```
aws ................ ionic-angular AWS Mobile Hub Starter
```

now  after project get created, when i do 'ionic serve'

its showing error as :

```
aws_mobile_analytics_app_id is not defined
```

I don't know what 'aws mobile analytics app id' is and for what pupose it can be use .

Can any one guide me for this one ?? 
Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out myself. Follow the steps below. When you create the ionic project with the aws argument - `ionic start myApp aws`, it creates a mobile-hub-project.zip file.

Log into your AWS account. In the Mobile Hub dashboard, click the "Import your project" button. Next, find the mobile-hub-project.zip included in this starter project, and drag and drop it to the import modal. Set the name of the project, and then click "Import project."

Once the project is imported, you'll be directed to the dashboard for this Mobile Hub project. To continue configuring the app, you'll need to find the name of the Amazon S3 bucket auto generated through the App Content Delivery system. To do this, click the "Resources" button on the left side of the Mobile Hub project dashboard, find the "Amazon S3 Buckets" card, and then copy the bucket name that contains contents delivery.

To install the AWS CLI, first ensure your pip installation is up to date:

pip install --upgrade pip
Next, install the AWS CLI:

pip install awscli

Next, assuming your terminal is still open inside of the myApp folder, run:

aws s3 cp s3://BUCKET_NAME/aws-config.js src/assets
Replacing BUCKET_NAME with the full name of the S3 bucket found above. This will copy the auto-generated aws-config.js file into the src/assets folder in your Ionic app, which pre-configures all your AWS settings automatically.